# Cython setup.py for several .pyx

Tags: python, compilation, installation, cython, setup.py

I would like to cythonize faster. Code for one .pyx is

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("MyFile.pyx")
)
```

What if i want to cythonize

- several files with ext .pyx, that i will call by their name
- all .pyx files in a folder

What would be python code for the setup.py in both cases ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-distutils_preprocessing

```
# several files with ext .pyx, that i will call by their name
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("primes",       ["primes.pyx"]),
    Extension("spam",         ["spam.pyx"]),
    ...
]

setup(
  name = 'MyProject',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
)
```

```
# all .pyx files in a folder
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'MyProject',
  ext_modules = cythonize(["*.pyx"]),
)
```

Comment: Hey what if I wanted to put libraries and include_dirs in code. Nad everyname ofr pyx in the same. So i have one .so file

Answer (score 23):

The answer above wasn't completely clear to me. To cythonize two files in different directories, simply list them inside of the cythonize(...) function:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(["folder1/file1.pyx", "folder2/file2.pyx"])
)
```