# Compile file with two separate libraries in Cython

Tags: cython, setuptools, distutils, python-extensions

I wrote a library in Cython that has two different "modes":

1. If rendering, I compile using GLFW.
2. If not rendering, I compile using EGL, which is faster, but I have not figured out how to render with it.

What is the recommended way to handle this situation?

Right now, I have the following directory structure:

```
mujoco
├── __init__.py
├── simEgl.pyx
├── simGlfw.pyx
├── sim.pxd
└── sim.pyx
```

`simEgl.pyx` contains EGL code and `simGlfw.pyx` contains GLFW code. `setup.py` uses an environment variable to choose one or the other for the build.

This works ok, except that I need to recompile the code every time I want to switch between modes. There must be a better way.

## Update

I agree that the best approach is to simultaneously compile two different libraries and use a toggle to choose which one to import. I already do have a base class in `sim.pyx` with shared functionality. However this base class must itself be compiled with the separate libraries. Specifically, `sim.pyx` depends on `libmujoco.so` which depends on either GLFW or EGL.

Here is my exhaustive search of possible approaches:

1. If I do not compile an extension for `sim.pyx`, I get `ImportError: No module named 'mujoco.sim'`
2. If I compile an extension for `sim.pyx` without including graphics libraries in the extension, I get `ImportError: /home/ethanbro/.mujoco/mjpro150/bin/libmujoco150.so: undefined symbol: __glewBlitFramebuffer`
3. If I compile an extension for `sim.pyx` and choose one set of graphics libraries (GLFW), then when I try to use the other set of graphics libraries (EGL) this does not work either unsurprisingly: 
   `ERROR: GLEW initalization error: Missing GL version`
4. If I compile two different versions of the `sim.pyx` library, one with one set of libraries, one with the other, I get: `TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()` which is not a very helpful error message, but appears to result from trying to share a source file between two different extensions.

Something like option 4 should be possible. In fact, if I were working in raw C, I would simply build two shared objects side by side using the different libraries. Any advice on how to get around this Cython limitation would be very welcome.

Comment: You probably want to just build both as separate extension modules? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826294/3657742 as an example

Comment: I largely agree with @chrisb. You write two extension modules with identical interfaces and use a `if rendering: import simGlfw as s; else: import  simEgl as s`. That might change if you want to use Cython (i.e. compile-time) features but if that's the case you need to give more detail (a common base class might be a good solution though)

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go. However, it does require compiling `sim.pyx` file into two different `.so` files. I tries doing this with `Extension(name='sim1', ...)` and `Extension(name='sim2', ...) ` but this caused an Import Error. Perhaps you can suggest a better way?

Comment: @chrisb, the critical difference between my situation and the post you referenced is that that post does not need the same source in two separate extensions.

Comment: @ethanabrooks (Not 100% sure but...) Cython/Python modules get their name from the source filename, which I think is what is causing you problems. What you could try is creating two almost empty .pyx files with the correct name, and use [Cython's little used include mechanism](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#the-include-statement) to load the shared code in each of them.

Comment: @DavidW that worked. Post an answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer is just a summary of the comments with a bit more explanation.)

My initial suggestion was to create two extension modules defining a common interface. That way you pick which to import in Python but be able to use them in the same way once imported:

```
if rendering:
   import simGlfw as s
else:
   import simEgl as s
s.do_something() # doesn't matter which you imported
```

It appears from the comments that the two modules also share a large chunk of their code and its really just the library that they're linked with that defines how they behave. Trying to re-use the same sources with

```
Extension(name='sim1', sources=["sim.pyx",...)
Extension(name='sim2', sources=["sim.pyx",...)
```

fails. This is because Cython assumes that the module name will be the same as the filename, and so creates a function `PyInit_sim` (on Python 3 - Python 2 is named slightly differently but the idea is the same). However, when you import sim1.so it looks for the function `PyInit_sim1`, fails to find it, and gives an error.

An easy way round it is to put the common code in "sim.pxi" and use [Cython's largely obsolete include mechanism](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#the-include-statement) to textually include that code in sim1.pyx and sim2.pyx

```
include "sim.pxi"
```

Although `include` is generally no longer recommended and `cimport` is preferred since it provides more "Python-like" behaviour, `include` is a simple solution to this particular problem.